# Reset to previous commit in a separate directory

Tags: git, terminal, bitbucket

Some files in my project has changed as I updated cocoapods. I've used bitbucket to keep my changes. Now, I want to download the previous commit (with an id) to a different directory and just copy/paste the necessary files. And I don't want the download to affect anything on git (until I copy/paste files). First I `git clone` the project to a different folder.

Now, I came across to

`git reset --hard` & `git reset --soft`

I couldn't really get what are the main differences. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man git`:

```
    git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]
       This form resets the current branch head to <commit> and possibly updates the index (resetting it to the tree of <commit>) and the working tree depending on <mode>. If <mode> is omitted, defaults to
       "--mixed". The <mode> must be one of the following:

       --soft
           Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets the head to <commit>, just like all modes do). This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would
           put it.

       --mixed
           Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.

           If -N is specified, removed paths are marked as intent-to-add (see git-add(1)).

       --hard
           Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since <commit> are discarded.

       --merge
           Resets the index and updates the files in the working tree that are different between <commit> and HEAD, but keeps those which are different between the index and working tree (i.e. which have
           changes which have not been added). If a file that is different between <commit> and the index has unstaged changes, reset is aborted.

           In other words, --merge does something like a git read-tree -u -m <commit>, but carries forward unmerged index entries.

       --keep
           Resets index entries and updates files in the working tree that are different between <commit> and HEAD. If a file that is different between <commit> and HEAD has local changes, reset is aborted.
```

So the difference is that --hard will throw away any local changes to files that are under Git's control. --soft on the other hand only makes the symbolic reference HEAD point to an earlier commit id.

Comment: So, if I want to have the copy of the previous commit in a different directory, without affecting anything on git, should i use hard or soft?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean with "without affecting ... git" and what exactly you mean with "copy of the commit". If I understand you correctly, I would guess that want to do a --hard reset, because of the whole "copying and different directory" story. However, I am sure you could reach your goal easier with other git commands, but you would have to reformulate your question more clearly.